# How can I open multiple forms inside a form

Tags: c#

I have 2 forms, Form1.cs and Form2.cs. When I use this method:

```
var form= new Form2();
form.Show();
```

it opens me a new form, but I want to open inside the form1.cs, not another window with this form.

Comment: Would an MDI form be suitable for you?

Comment: Look at this documentation on how to create MDI parent and child forms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-mdi-child-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 1):

You can add a panel control to your main form or to your form1 then add a button.
Put this code in;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2() { TopLevel = false, TopMost = true };
    frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
    this.pContainer.Controls.Add(frm);
    frm.Show();
}
```

Please check this link https://foxlearn.com/windows-forms/how-to-add-the-form-in-panel-from-another-form-in-csharp-442.html

Comment: As I understood, you wanna use UserControl and you can look at this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZ63E_9ASwM

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution as @John said  you can use MDI form. Please check the code and the link below.

```
  protected void MDIChildNew_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
      Form2 newMDIChild = new Form2();
      // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
      newMDIChild.MdiParent =this;
      // Display the new form.
      newMDIChild.Show();
  }
```

**Note:** Here is the link given [Creating an MDI Child Form in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manish1231/creating-an-mdi-child-form-in-C-Sharp/)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign Form1 as the owner of Form2 in Form.Show() method:

```
    var form = new Form2();
    form.Show(this); // assuming you are calling this method from Form1 (this = form1)
```