# How do I add multiple forms inside one on Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I am making a project inside of Visual Studio 2019 with the language C#. I've been looking for an answer to this question for quite some time.

What I am trying to achieve:
There will be multiple tabs across the side of a panel, when a button is pressed it will display
another page inside of a specific area, instead of needing to show a whole different other form. I've
tried using tabs but the buttons are not customizable nor can I arrange the position of each button
individually.

Thank you and I hope somebody can help.

Comment: Are you looking something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962341/how-to-load-form-inside-panel-other-form-in-win-app ?

Comment: If this is Windows Forms, please add a "winforms" tag. There are so many UI frameworks and the answer depends on which you use.

Comment: If you don't TabPages in a Tab you can still achieve the same effect using buttons of your own and __UserControls__. These are like Forms but meant to be nested in some container, like in a Panel. Like a Form they can be reused, are classes of their own and are created as parioal classes.. Just make sure to create suitable interfaces to share/exchange data and/or events..

Answer (score -1):

I have answered the same from this thread [How can I open multiple forms inside a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66133016/how-can-i-open-multiple-forms-inside-a-form/66133102#66133102)

You can generate a form inside a panel. By doing this below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2() { TopLevel = false, TopMost = true };
    frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
    this.pContainer.Controls.Add(frm);
    frm.Show();
}
```

For you to know more about this with video guide just check this website.

https://foxlearn.com/windows-forms/how-to-add-the-form-in-panel-from-another-form-in-csharp-442.html

pContainer is a panel control.
Btw Topmost is optional depending on how you use it.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything named pContainer or Panel Control, is there a package to install?

Comment: If you really really want to use a Form as a UserControl, don't set its borders. Also, setting `TopLevel = false, TopMost = true` is kind of pointless: `TopMost` is just cached and not set when `TopLevel = false`. Just `BringToFront()` it. UserControls also have a Designer, so...

Comment: @FIVEPZ the pContainer is a panel Control.

Comment: Despite the title OP doesn't really seem to want real forms just a better Tab control, so replacing TabPages by UserControl and coding the show/hide with his own buttons should do..